# How to installation startup-manager on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: apt, 13.10, startupmanager

I want to install startup-manager on Ubuntu 13.10. I want to enable an older kernel, to see installed services, etc.

I typed the code `sudo apt-get install startup-manager` but I get the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package startup-manager
```

Comment: It's not in the repos apparently. What's startup-manager? Do you have a link to it's web page?

Answer (score 4):

**startup-manager** is no longer available in Ubuntu 13.10

Try Grub Customizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. I installed Grub Customizer. Problem solved. May God bless you!

Comment: On Ubuntu 20 just: `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`.